# C# xml (de)serialization of child objects

Tags: c#, xml

i have the following class structure

```
[Serializable]
public class Manager
{
    List<item> items
    List<Mod> mods

    [XmlArray("Items"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(Item), ElementName = "Item")]
    public List<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
    }

    [XmlArray("Mods"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(Mod), ElementName = "Mod")]
    public List<Mod> Mods
    {
        get
        {
            return mods;
        }
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    string name;
    Mod mod;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
    public Mod Mod
    {
        get
        {
            return mod;
        }
        set
        {
            mod = value;
        }
    }

    private Item()
    { }

    public Item(string name, Mod mod)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Mod = mod;
    }
}
```

Serialization goes as expected, but when i deserialize i want the item.Mod object to point to the object in the mods list. instead it creates a new instance. 
Is there a way to do this?

What i do now is manually gather the correct instances after deserialization

```
foreach (Item item in instance.Items)
{
  item.Mod = instance.Mods.Find(x => x.Name == item.Mod.Name);
}
```

If it is not possible, then is there a way to only serialize the mod.Name in the item? (so the mod itself should serialize fully, but the item.mod should only serialize the name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set this manually after deserializing. During deserialization, your constructor is not being called. That's default behaviour.

Comment: What i'm doing now is manually setting the item.mod to the mod i find in the mods list. Is that what you're saying?     foreach (Item item in instance.Items)
                    {
                        item.Mod = instance.Mods.Find(x => x.Name == item.Mod.Name);
                    }

Comment: Yes, exactly :). I had the same problem and solved it the same way.